# What's the difference between pipes and subprocess module?

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I am getting confused with pipes and subprocess module.

here is my code:

```
import pipes
import subprocess


with open('123.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('a line 1\n')
    f.write('a line 2\n')

t = pipes.Template()
t.append('grep a', '--')
f = t.open('123.txt', 'r')
print(f.readlines())

with open('123.txt', 'r') as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen('grep a', stdin=f, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

print(p.readlines())
```

their outputs are exactly the same:

```
['a line 1\n', 'a line 2\n']
['a line 1\n', 'a line 2\n']
```

My question is:

1. What's the difference between these two modules.
2. Can I write strings through a subprocess.PIPE(stdin) and redirect to another subprocess.PIPE(stdout). In this situation what `args` should I use in `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: See the Python documentation -- `subprocess` is intended to replace *all* other command invocation methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is it? The documentation specifically mentions it aims to replace `os.system` & `os.spawn*`. There is no mention of the `pipes` module anywhere in the `subprocess` docs or its associated PEP.

Comment: @BAKEZQ, ...asking three questions in one "question" is one reason. Asking a tool-selection question is another. Though those are both reasons to close (as too-broad and as off-topic, respectively) rather than to downvote.

Comment: I can't find any question related to the difference between pipes and subprocess in stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: `subprocess` does specifically mention ["Replacing shell pipelines"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) which is the job `pipes` exists for. I suspect they don't mention `pipes` simply because they forgot about it; `pipes` is *NIX specific, barely maintained or publicized, and built on the semi-deprecated `os.system`/`os.pipe` calls that `subprocess` specifically exists to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with `subprocess`. `pipes` is *NIX specific, barely maintained, and built on the semi-deprecated `os.system`/`os.pipe` primitives that `subprocess` exists to replace. While `subprocess` doesn't specifically mention the `pipes` module, it does provide examples for [Replacing shell pipelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) which will handle the cases you seem to care about, and without the shells implicitly involved in `pipes` (due to it being built on `os.system`/`os.popen`), `subprocess` can be safer and faster (if you don't use `shell=True` that is) and more portable to boot.